# Как создать такую шторку, которая выдвигается снизу вверх при свайпе?

Tags: android

Я не могу найти в интернете информацию об этой шторке. Заранее спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: BottomSheet https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он явно не по теме.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать. [BottomSheet](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior). Для большинства подобных кейсов это самое простое решение.

Если вы хотите затемнять экран на фоне, вы в целом можете открывать новую Activity предварительно убрав анимации появления и фон. В качестве фона можно поставить полупрозрачную View, как на скриншоте. Но тогда вам нужно обработать клики за пределами BottomSheet (к примеру закрывать BottomSheet и Activity).

Вот пару статей:

- [Android Bottom Sheet / Bottom Sheet Behavior](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-bottom-sheet-7e9cfcec6427)
- [Android: выдвигающийся экран снизу](https://habr.com/ru/post/309200/)

Если вам по каким-то причинам не подходит данный инструмент, вы можете унаследоваться от BottomSheet и переопределить его методы.

В целом такое же поведение можно сделать и простым Fragment-ом. Но тут вам придется самому обрабатывать его поведение, анимации и прочие штуки. Но иногда это бывает более подходящим вариантом.